# Java error:cannot find symbol in a very simple program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I recently started programming in Java. I've made a couple of easy programs with classes and everything, but this one is giving me a hard time and I've got no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class Plane {
    int numberOfRows = 27;
    int [][] row1 = new int [numberOfRows][3];
    int [][] row2 = new int [numberOfRows][3];

    public void airPlane() {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            System.out.print(row1[i]+"  ");
            System.out.print(row2[i]+"  ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        Plane airPlane = new Plane();
        airPlane.airPlane();
    }
}
```

Every time i try to run it it gives me

```
    Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Plane airPlane = new Plane();
        ^
  symbol:   class Plane 
  location: class Main

Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Plane airPlane = new Plane();
                             ^
  symbol:   class Plane
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

Comment: Did you import the `Plane` class properly?

Comment: Is your code in packages? Is `Plane.java` in the same folder as `Main.java`?

Comment: You need to import `Plane` in your `Main` class. Since both programs are in different files.

Comment: Are you not using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse)?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but it won't run it at all

Comment: I compile it with javac
Plane an Main are in the same folder & package

Comment: Class `Plane` has to be in file `Plane.java` in the same directory as your `Main` class.

Comment: How are you running javac?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you have two files here ("Main.java", "Plane.java", correct), or only a single file (wrong)?

Comment: If the two are in the same file, delete the `public` from `Plane` A file can't have two `public` classes

Comment: There are two files
Main.java & Plane.java

Comment: @user3139935 `javac *.java`

Comment: *Exactly* what text do you have in each file? (Does `javac *.java` work any better?)

Comment: Yeah I say Plane is not compiled. Try clean an build if running from IDE.

Comment: javac *.java doesn't work at all. I have the text i have posted + package homework23 at the top of each file

Comment: You haven't provided an SSCCE. Please do. (We can't guess the answer from incomplete information.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe you mistyped the package name in one of your files. Because for me using "package homework23;" at the top of each class it compiles fine with "javac *.java".

Comment: Modify Main.java's main to be "public static main(String[] args)". Put both these files in the same directory and execute javac *.java from that directory. It should compile. Then, do "java Main" and it should print some output.